# ANTLR 4 - not parsing correctly

Tags: antlr, antlr4

```
grammar Expr;

// parser rules
prog : ((decl_list expr | expr) ';' NEWLINE?)*;

decl_list : decl decl_list
     | decl
     ;

decl : DEF FUN var_list '=' expr ENDEF
     | DEF FUN '=' expr ENDEF
     ;

var_list : PARAM var_list 
     | PARAM 
     ;

expr : LET VAR '=' expr IN              # assignExpr
     | FUN '()'                         # callExpr
     | FUN '(' expr_list ')'            # callExpr
     | expr ('*'|'/') expr              # infixExpr
     | expr ('+'|'-') expr              # infixExpr 
     | '(' expr ')'                     # parensExpr
     | num                              # numberExpr
     | '~' expr                         # negateExpr
     | VAR                              # varExpr
     ;

expr_list : expr',' expr_list
     | expr
     ;

num  : '-'? INT
     | '-'? FLOAT
     ;

// lexer rules                    
NEWLINE: [\r\n]+ ;
INT: [0-9]+ ;          // should handle negatives
FLOAT: [0-9]+'.'[0-9]* ; // should handle signs(+/-)
WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
VAR: [a-zA-Z_-]+;
PARAM: [a-zA-Z_]+;
FUN: [a-zA-Z0-9]+;
DEF: 'def';
ENDEF: 'endef';
LET: 'let';
IN: 'in';
```

i am currently making f1vae parser with antlr4.
the line starts from prog, declares function by decl_list, and interprete expr with declared functions.

the problem happens when i put this:

```
def f = 3 endef def g x y = x + y endef let x = f() in g(1,x);
```

it gets this error message

```
line 1:4 missing ';' at 'f'
line 1:6 mismatched input '=' expecting {';', '*', '/', '+', '-'}
```

why is this happening?
tried changing parser orders, but didn't work.

Comment: The first thing you should always do when you have a parse error: check what tokens the lexer produced. Is that what the parser expects? And in your grammar I see multiple overlapping tokens (e.g. VAR, PARAM and FUN). You cannot define rules like that. How should the lexer decide which of the 3 to use with an input like `abc`? What it actually does is to pick the first rule that matches, which is very likely not want you want (hence the tip to check the token list).

Comment: how can i check tokens the lexer produced?

Comment: By getting the token list from the tokens stream and printing it somewhere. TypeScript code: `const tokens = this.tokenStream.getTokens();
        tokens.forEach((token) => {
            console.log(token.toString());
        });`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments: you have overlapping lexer rules. For example, the input `"in"` can be matched by the following lexer rules:

```
VAR: [a-zA-Z_-]+;
PARAM: [a-zA-Z_]+;
FUN: [a-zA-Z0-9]+;
IN: 'in';
```

And when input can be matched by multiple rules, ANTLR will pick the first one. So, `"in"` will *always* become a `VAR` token.

Instead, try something like this:

```
grammar Expr;

// parser rules
prog : ((decl_list expr | expr) ';' NEWLINE?)*;

decl_list : decl decl_list
     | decl
     ;

decl : DEF fun var_list '=' expr ENDEF
     | DEF fun '=' expr ENDEF
     ;

var_list : param var_list
     | param
     ;

expr : LET var '=' expr IN expr         # assignExpr
     | fun '(' ')'                      # callExpr
     | fun '(' expr_list ')'            # callExpr
     | expr ('*'|'/') expr              # infixExpr
     | expr ('+'|'-') expr              # infixExpr
     | '(' expr ')'                     # parensExpr
     | num                              # numberExpr
     | '~' expr                         # negateExpr
     | var                              # varExpr
     ;

expr_list : expr',' expr_list
     | expr
     ;

num  : '-'? INT
     | '-'? FLOAT
     ;

var: ID;
param: ID;
fun: ID;

// lexer rules
NEWLINE: [\r\n]+ ;
INT: [0-9]+ ;          // should handle negatives
FLOAT: [0-9]+'.'[0-9]* ; // should handle signs(+/-)
WS: [ \t]+ -> skip;
DEF: 'def';
ENDEF: 'endef';
LET: 'let';
IN: 'in';
ID : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z0-9_-]*; // Place this after your keyword rules!
```