# antlr4 - mismatched input and not catching function syntax in lexer

Tags: antlr, antlr4

```
grammar Expr;

// parser rules
prog : ((decl_list expr_seq | expr_seq) ';' NEWLINE?)*;

decl_list : decl (decl)*;

expr_seq : expr (expr)*;

decl : DEF fun var_list '=' expr ENDEF
     | DEF fun '=' expr ENDEF
     ;

var_list : param (param)*;

expr_list : expr (',' expr)*;

expr : LET var '=' expr IN expr             # assignExpr
     | fun '()'                         # callExpr
     | fun '(' expr_list ')'            # callExpr
     | expr ('*'|'/') expr              # infixExpr
     | expr ('+'|'-') expr              # infixExpr 
     | '(' expr ')'                     # parensExpr
     | num                              # numberExpr
     | '~' expr                         # negateExpr
     | var                              # varExpr
     ;

num  : '-'? INT
     | '-'? FLOAT
     ;

fun  : STR (('0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9') STR)*;

var  : STR (('_' | '-') STR)*;

param : STR ('_' STR)*;

// lexer rules                    
NEWLINE: [\r\n]+ ;
INT: [0-9]+ ;          // should handle negatives
FLOAT: [0-9]+'.'[0-9]* ; // should handle signs(+/-)
WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
DEF: 'def';
ENDEF: 'endef';
LET: 'let';
IN: 'in';
STR: [a-zA-Z]+;
```

i am currently making f1vae with antlr4 in java.
above is the current parser and lexer rules.

when i put g(1,x); for input:

```
line 1:2 mismatched input '1' expecting {'(', '-', '~', INT, FLOAT, 'let', STR}
```

this error message occurs.
isnt '1' a INT? why is this error happening?

also, the lexer/parser seems to think g as a variable, not a function name.

```
(prog (expr_seq (expr (var g)) (expr ( (expr 1 ,) x ))) ; \n)
```

this is the input with

```
grun Expr prog -tree
```

how can i solve these problem?
tried removing overlapping lexer rules. but didn't work.

Comment: This is exactly the same as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77617820/antlr-4-not-parsing-correctly : your rules DIGIT and INT overlap.

Comment: i think that is not the problem. if i remove DIGIT and replace it with ('0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9') in the parser rule, the error still happens.

Comment: Yes, it _is_ the same problem. When you do `'0'`, `'1'`, ... inside a parser rule, ANTLR will create lexer rules for these "literal tokens" like this: `T__0 : '0';`, `T__1 : '1';`, ... And these `T__?` tokens are overlapping with your `INT` rule.

Comment: Better to remove these `'0'`, `'1'`, ... tokens from your parser rules and just use `INT` there. After parsing, you can validate that the `INT` tokens used in a `fun` rule are really made out of 1 digit (and throw an error if they're not).